Python tkinter window keeps closing and I'm not sure why
I'm trying to make a fun little program where a furret will walk across the screen every hour or so. I have a main window that starts a loop that plays the animation/sound every hour or so, but after the first time the pokemon finishes his walk, the entire program ends. I think it may have something to do with how I've set up the tkinter windows, but I can't figure it out.
I don't think it's proper to include the entire code here, but I'm new and I have no idea what I'm doing so please bear with me.
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from random import randint
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import threading
import time

class MyFrame(Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.status = StringVar(self, 'Not Walking')
        self.walking = False
        self.showAnimation = None
        self.createWidgets()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.mainLabel = Label(self, text= "<>FURRET WALK<>")
        self.statusLabel = Label(self, textvariable= self.status)
        self.startButton = Button(self, text="START", command= self.starter)
        self.endButton = Button(self, text="END", command= self.endWalk)

        self.mainLabel.pack(expand=True)
        self.statusLabel.pack(expand=True)
        self.startButton.pack(expand=True)
        self.endButton.pack(expand=True)

    def playSong(self):
        num = randint(1,6)
        path = ""
        match num:
            case 1:
                path = "1-17. Accumula Town.wav"
            case 2:
                path = "1-32. The Dreamyard.wav"
            case 3:
                path = "1-51. Castelia City.wav"
            case 4:
                path = "1-61. Bicycle.wav"
            case 5:
                path = "2-02. Driftveil City.wav"
            case 6:
                path = "2-08. Mistralton City.wav"
        song = AudioSegment.from_wav(path)
        audio = song[:43*1000]
        play(audio)

    def animation(self, extraWindow, count, imageObject, gifLabel, frames):
        newImage = imageObject[count]

        try:
            gifLabel.configure(image=newImage)
        except:
            pass
        count += 1
        if count == frames:
            count = 0
        try:
            self.showAnimation = extraWindow.after(20, lambda: self.animation(extraWindow, count, imageObject, gifLabel, frames))
        except:
            pass

    def moveWindow(self, extraWindow,moveX,moveY,startX,startY,dirX,dirY,width,yCumulitive,avgY):
        extraWindow.geometry(f"128x72+{moveX+startX}+{moveY+startY}")
        if dirY:
            yCumulitive += avgY
            if yCumulitive > 1:
                yCumulitive = 0
                moveY += 1
        else:
            yCumulitive += avgY
            if yCumulitive > 1:
                yCumulitive = 0
                moveY -= 1
        if dirX:
            moveX += 2
            if moveX > width+128:
                extraWindow.destroy()
        else:
            moveX -= 2
            if moveX < (width+128)*-1:
                extraWindow.destroy()
        time.sleep(0.05)
        try:
            extraWindow.after(150, self.moveWindow(extraWindow,moveX,moveY,startX,startY,dirX,dirY,width,yCumulitive,avgY))
        except:
            pass

    def createWindow(self):
        extraWindow = Toplevel()

        count = 0
        moveX = 0
        moveY = 0
        width = extraWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
        height = extraWindow.winfo_screenheight()
        dirX = True
        dirY = True
        startX = randint(-128, -127)
        startY = randint(0, height)
        if startX == -127:
            dirX = False
            startX = width
        yTarget = startY
        if randint(1,3) > 1:
            yTarget = (float(randint(0, width))*0.25)*2
        if randint(1,2) == 2:
            dirY = False
        if (startY - yTarget) < 0:
            dirY = True
        if (startY + yTarget) > height:
            dirY = False
        tics = width/2
        yDistance = yTarget - startY
        avgY = yDistance/tics

        extraWindow.geometry(f"128x72+{startX}+{startY}")
        extraWindow.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
        extraWindow.overrideredirect(True)
        extraWindow.attributes("-transparentcolor", "white")

        if dirX:
            gifImage = "furret.gif"
        else:
            gifImage = "furret-right-to-left.gif"
        
        openImage = Image.open(gifImage)

        frames = openImage.n_frames

        imageObject = [PhotoImage(file=gifImage, format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]

        gifLabel = Label(extraWindow, image="")
        gifLabel.place(x=0,y=0,width=128,height=72)

        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.playSong)
        t1.start()

        self.animation(extraWindow, count, imageObject, gifLabel, frames)
        self.moveWindow(extraWindow,moveX,moveY,startX,startY,dirX,dirY,width,0,avgY)

    def startWalk(self):
        self.walking = True
        self.status.set("Walking!")
        while(self.walking):
            self.createWindow()
            add = randint(1800, 3600)
            time.sleep(3600)

    def starter(self):
        ts = threading.Thread(target=self.startWalk, args=())
        ts.start()
        

    def endWalk(self):
        self.walking = False
        self.status.set("Not Walking")


def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Furret Walk!")
    root.geometry("300x100")
    frame = MyFrame(root)
    frame.pack()
    root.mainloop()

main()

I've tried changing the location of the while loop that's supposed to keep the program running, but it just breaks everything.
Basically, main creates a small window populated by widgets generated from the createWidgets() function. I press the start button, that runs starter(), which creates a thread for the startWalk() function. startWalk() should continue to play until I hit the end button, which triggers endWalk() which turns the while loop condition to false. But as stated, the program ends after the first time the furret walks across the screen.
Upon messing around, I think it's more related to the threads I have set up, as when the t1 thread, which exists to play the music, finishes playing its song, the program ends. I'm unsure how this is related.

extraWindow.after(150, self.moveWindow(...)) is an immediate call to moveWindow(), followed 150 milliseconds later by nothing happening at all (since the method didn't return anything for after() to schedule later).  This can be fixed with a lambda, just as you did in your other use of .after().

Also, you're probably right that it's not proper to include the entire code. Read [mre] - best practice is to gradually figure out what exactly is at fault, then ask a question with the minimal code required to reproduce your example. (Being laborious is half the point; the optimal case is for you to not need the question in the first place!)

I feel like this might be easier in pygame
